# How to automatically check downloaded gzip file for corruption?

Tags: batch-file, zip, gzip, winrar

I have a batch file that automatically downloads a gzip file.  I want to check if the gzip file is corrupt, if not, re-download / run download batch file again.

What is the best way to automatically download a .gz file from a URL, check it for corruption, keep downloading until the file downloads successfully and is not corrupt?

Comment: I guess you want to repeat the download if the ZIP file *is* corrupt... anyway, show us what you have tried so far and tell us where you are stuck...

Comment: So is it gzip or is it zip? You are mixing up the terms.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is really `gzip` (not zip , tar.gz or whatever else) it can be examined with [`gzipjs.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/gzipJS.bat) . To download a file you can use [`winhhtpjs.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) . If you have both scripts then you can:

```
@echo off


for /l %%# in (1;1;5) do (

    rem ==== Change the link and file name bellow  =======
    call winhhtpjs.bat https://someserver.com/file.gzip -saveTo "%cd%\file.gzip"
    call gzipjs -k file.gzip 5
    rem ====================================================
    if errorlevel 5 (
        goto :break_for
    )
)

echo --Failed 5 times--
exit /b %errorlevel%
:break_for

echo --Success--
```

Comment: do you have an example without the limit of 5 attempts?

Comment: so that if the download fails or is corrupt, it keeps retrying until it is successful

Comment: @user3312792 , you can increase attempts on this line - `for /l %%# in (1;1;5) ` and instead of 5 to set a number you want.

Comment: Is there any kind of error visible in the console? May the downloaded file is not exactly in gzip format